# Spring JPA Update operation

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am working on Spring JPA. As part of it, I have to update an entity ignoring few attributes. The following code is in effort to implement the update operation.

```
@Transactional
    public void updateDMove(DTCRto jsonRto){
        //copyProperties(Object source, Object target, String[] ignoreProperties) 
        DMove dMoveDB = dMoveRepo.findDMove(jsonRto.getLn(), jsonRto.getDriver(), jsonRto.getType());
        DMove dMoveRto = jsonRto.convertToDMove(jsonRto);
        BeanUtils.copyProperties(dMoveRto,drayMoveDB, new String[] {"moveId", "created","lastchange","locations","status"});
        dMoveRepo.save(dMoveDB);
    }
```

DMove  : Model class which needs to be updated.
dMoveRepo : respective repository class.
dMoveRto : incoming object.
dMoveDb : object existing in the database.
moveId : is the PK in the DMove class.

Can anyone suggest me what is the way to implement the update operation in Spring JPA ?

Thanks.

Comment: The above code gives me an error : "org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: :

Comment: On your entity class on any relationship you have there (OneToMany, ManyToOne..) set the cascade mode to either `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` or `cascade = CascadeType.DEATACH`. Also your object and variable names don't look very clean, would recommend to give things meaningful names.

Comment: the entity classes have 'cascade = CascadeType.ALL'. As for the variables names i quickly had to change to post here. but thanks I will look into it anyways. Would cascadeType.Detach work differently ?

Answer (score 0):

`detached entity passed to persist` means that hibernate doesn't recognize the entity you passed to update, because `dMoveDB` isn't a `persistent` object, you lost that when you used this line `BeanUtils.copyProperties(dMoveRto,drayMoveDB, new String[] {"moveId", "created","lastchange","locations","status"});`

I suggest you remove the `moveId` so the entity you try to update keeps its orginal primary key and remains as  a `persistent` object.

One last thing, you have to make sure that the object you get from  `dMoveRepo.findDMove(...)` isn't `null`

Comment: the error is for "locations" model class which is a list. I removed the moveId . same error :-/